# Speed Up Keras LSTM

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train LSTM using Keras, but the training is extremely slow (I have gpu Nvidia Titan X). Does someone know how can I speed up my training speed ?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

replace standard `LSTM` to `CuDNNLSTM`. You can import it from,

```
from keras.layers import  CuDNNLSTM
```

Comment: Good to know.  Note though that it doesn't support masking nor custom activation nor dropout.  But is much faster!

Comment: Went from 43 seconds on a 1080 ti to 19 seconds per epoch!  Nice :)  Thank you!